# Extracting lines from a file using awk

Tags: regex, awk

I have an sql dump file, from which I want to extract the Insert statements. I'm trying to do this using `awk`.

The insert statements span multiple lines. They start with `INSERT` and end with a semicolon.

I have tried using:

```
awk '/INSERT*;/' dump.sql
```

But it doesn't work. What is the correct way of doing this? (My google-fu has failed on this one)

Thanks!

Comment: If your dump doesn't include semicolons in the data, you can try setting `FS=;` to split records on SQL statements.

Comment: regex is wrong, should be `/INSERT.*;/`, or better `/^INSERT.*;$/`. I have checked that my MySQL dump does not span multiple lines, maybe just soft wrap in your editor?

Comment: The .* notation makes sense, but doesn't seem to work. The dump file definitely uses semicolons as the delimiter. When I `cat` the dump file, it *does* span multiple lines. (I'd prefer not to use `^` and `$` because it seems that there can be spaces before and after).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For matching multiple lines:

```
/^INSERT/, /.*;/ {print}
```

Running at ideone [**here**](http://ideone.com/nVhPq)

Comment: What do the double `/x/,/y/` matches mean? Could you provide some link that explains this syntax? Thanks!

Comment: @Aku http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/gawk-3.1.0/html_chapter/gawk_8.html#SEC110

Comment: "What do the double /x/,/y/ matches mean"  This is called "line addressing".  It means print everything from a line starting with INSERT through to a line ending in ;

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (or what @belisarius suggests) works:

```
awk '{ if ($1 ~ /^\s*INSERT/) print $0 ";" }' RS=";" dump.sql
```

Setting the record separator is pretty simple and well-documented:

http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multiple-Line.html

I can't seem to find a reference for the double matches as in @belisarius's solution but I like it better.

Answer (score 0):

I think your just missing a "." as in `awk '/INSERT.*;/' dump.sql`